# WPF Dispatcher from Selfhost WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, owin

Im wondering what the correct usage of a dispatcher is from within an Owin selfhosted webapi controller? Im using ICommand(s) with a NotifyTaskbarIcon.

```
public HttpResponseMessage ShowPortalWindow()
{

var showPortalCommand = (App.Current as App).TaskbarCommands.ShowPortalCommand;
var dispather = Request.Properties["Dispatcher"] as Dispatcher;

if (!dispather.Invoke(() => showPortalCommand.CanExecute(url)))
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

    dispather.Invoke(() => showPortalCommand.Execute(url));
}
```

Do I need to invoke the first "CanExecute" method? It does not change any UI.

At first I was hoping to simply get main application (App) thread like this:

```
var mainApp = dispather.Invoke(() => (App.Current as App));
```

But that resulted in "The thread is already used by another process..".

Comment: var mainApp = dispather.Invoke(() => (App.Current as App)); Roughly translates to: "Invoke expression X *synchronously* on a dispatcher's thread". This thread is already used so by choosing "Invoke", you'd try to force whoever is using that thread to wait until your expression X finishes - this is why you're getting the exception. Try BeginInvoke instead and if it works, I'll promote my comment to an answer and flesh it out a bit.

Comment: The code you posted leaves me with a lot of questions, so I'd like to know more about it before I answer. (example: obtaining a thread of a different process?)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Im not able to use BeginInvoke as it takes different parameters. And example is most welcome. Im trying to change some UI in a window using an endpoint in a selfhost webapi as the trigger.

Comment: I'd love to help but I'm still not clear on what exactly you have in place. Simple diagram? :)